# Running iperf traffic using virtual interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, router, iptables

I have two linux PCs. One is configured as a IPERF server and another configured as a IPERF client. From the client PC, I have connected 12 units of DUT through managed switch with one port as TRUNK port configuration. At the other end of the DUT (RF) is connected to the CMTS and finally to the IPERF server PC that sits behind the CMTS.

All the DUT's BRLAN IP is 10.1.10.1 and hence I have configured one interface (eth0) of the IPERF client PC with static IP as 10.1.10.100 to reach the DUT.

Also, I have configured 12 virtual interfaces as follows in the client PC for each DUT.

```
eth0--10.1.10.100
eth0:101--10.1.10.101
eth0:102--10.1.10.102
eth0:103--10.1.10.103
eth0:104--10.1.10.104
....
eth0:112--10.1.10.112
```

This is created in order to run traffic across different DUTs at the same time.

I will run the following command in the IPERF server PC

```
iperf -s
```

I will run the following command in IPERF client

```
iperf -c <Server IP> -B 10.1.10.101 -t 100s --> for DUT1
iperf -c <Server IP> -B 10.1.10.102 -t 100s --> for DUT2
```

similarly I will run the command for 12 DUTs so that each DUT receives the IPERF traffic

I am not seeing the packet going out the Client PC at all?

Can anyone point out the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your configuration is.

But assuming DUT = device under test, BRLAN = bridged LAN, then this vaguely looks like you've connected twelve devices that all have the same IP to a switch. And you are trying to compensate for that by giving the PC that runs IPERF and is also connected to that switch thirteen different IP addresses.

This is not going to work. If the devices all have the same IP address, you need some way to distinguish between them in your network. One option is to use VLAN: Configure your switch to add a different VLAN tag for each of the devices.

On the IPERF server side, keep in mind that your "virtual interfaces" are not really virtual interfaces, instead they are just the old way of assigning multiple IPv4 addresses to a single interface (`ip addr` will list all of the addresses). Instead, add proper VLAN interfaces.

Then you still have a routing problem, because you must distinguish the VLAN interface by *source* address, instead of destination address. So read up on *policy routing*, and add routes for each of your device.

(It would be much simpler if you could just assign each of your devices a different IP address, e.g. with DHCP).